# Update injected model from route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update some values and it's creating a new one instead of updating the selected data

this is the controller code

```php
public function update(Request $request, Payment_Student $payment_Student)
{        
   $payment_Student->date =request('date');
   $payment_Student->amount =request('amount');
   $payment_Student->formation_id =request('formation_id');
   $payment_Student->student_id =request('student_id');
   $payment_Student->save();
   return redirect()->route('payment.index');
}
```

> This is my route code

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/search','CategoryController@search');
Route::resource('/category','CategoryController');
Route::resource('/formation','FormationController');
Route::resource('/professor','ProfessorController');
Route::resource('/student','StudentController');
Route::resource('/classroom','ClassroomController');
Route::resource('/session','SessionController');
Route::resource('/payment','PaymentController');
Route::resource('/seance','SeanceController');
Route::resource('/paymentprof','PaymentProfessorController');
Route::resource('/paymentstudent','PaymentStudentController');
Route::resource('/presence','PresenceController');
Route::resource('/profile','ProfileController');
```

> This is my balde view code

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('paymentstudent.update',$payment_Student->id)}}" class="form-horizontal">
  {{method_field('PATCH')}}
  @csrf
  Date:
   <br/>
  <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date">
  <br/>
  Amount:
  <input  type="number"  value="{{$payment_Student->amount}}"  name="amount" 
  class="form-control">
  <br/>
  Formation:
  <select class="form-control" name="formation_id">
        @foreach($formation as $formation)
    <option value="{{$formation->id}}">{{$formation->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
  <br/>
  Student:
  <select class="form-control" name="student_id">
         @foreach($student as $student)
    <option value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->lastname}}</option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
  <div class="card-footer">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
         </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

when I select a data to update it creates new data the updated value that I have inserted

Comment: `dd($payment_Student);` on the top of your function to see if you're actually getting the existing object and not instantiating a new one

Comment: I am getting empty array

Comment: That's the issue, you're not passing the model from your route, add you Blade View code

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: getting this error {{ Creating default object from empty value }}

Comment: Inspect `{{route('paymentstudent.update',$payment_Student->id)}}` in your HTML, what URL does it generate?

Comment: try renaming your variable to `$paymentstudent` ? `public function update(Request $request, Payment_Student $paymentstudent)`

Comment: @CaddyDZ This is the UR L( paymentstudent/27/edit)  the current URL that i select

Comment: @cbaconnier works like a treat thanks man

Comment: @CaddyDZ thanks man i appreciate it a lot thanks for your time

Comment: @MohamedMidou I did an answer, with a more detailled explanation. You can validate it to close the question :) It would be appreciated

Comment: @cbaconnier how do i validate your answer am new to stack overflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when you make a `resource` laravel will singularize the resource name and make a variable out of it.

Example: `Route::resource('videos', 'VideoController')` laravel will expect the variable `$video`

In your case, `paymentstudent` will probably give the variable `$paymentstudent`

Fortunatly, you can customize your own parameter name

```
Route::resource('paymentstudent', 'PaymentStudentController', ['parameters' => [
    'paymentstudent' => 'payment_Student'
]]);
```